# "legen" vs "liegen"

Tags: meaning

I get confused between the verbs [legen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/legen#German) and [liegen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liegen#German). I would appreciate some explantation on the meaning of the two verbs, preferably with examples. Also, are there context where te two verbs are synonymous?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference is that `liegen` is used to describe where something is located while is used `legen` to describe the act of placing it. For instance you would have:

> The rug lies on the floor.
>
> Der Teppich liegt auf dem Boden

But if you were talking about placing the rug on the floor, you would say:

> I lay the rug on the floor.
>
> Ich lege den Teppich auf den Boden.

In the first example, notice that you use an indirect object to describe the location, but in the second you would use the accusative for both the object being positioned and the location.

Comment: So, they are more or less analogous to english "lay" and "lie"?

Answer (score 8):

[Glenn's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/6522/992%20%22%22) is pretty much spot on. I would like to add that when you place something such that it has a tendency to be tipped over (vase etc) 'stellen' is more appropriate than 'legen'. But yes, the pairs liegen/legen & stehen/stellen are analogous.

As per their usage in a sentence, legen is a Bewegungsverb (movement verb) like 'gehen' and liegen is Nicht-Bewegungsverb (non-movement verb) like 'schlafen'. Therefore, you have to use accusative and dative cases in Wechselpräposition as well as 'sein' and 'haben' as helping verbs in perfect form respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This also applies to *sitzen*/*setzen* (Analogous to English sit/set).

> Ich sitze auf dem Stuhl. — dative, no motion
>   Ich setze das Buch auf den Stuhl. — accusative, motion
>   Ich setze mich auf den Stuhl. — accusative, motion

Comment: "This..." What?

Comment: Man kann ein Buch auf einen Stuhl **legen**, aber nicht **setzen**. Bücher werden gelesen, gekauft, weggeworfen, geworfen, gelegt, und einiges anderes, aber Bücher werden nicht gesetzt.

Comment: @Hubert: Diesen Fehler mache ich immer weider. Kannst du eine allgemeine Regel fuer "setzen" erlaeutern? Im Englischen kann absolut jedes Gegenstand gesetzt ("place" or "put") werden.

Comment: @DavidWright: 1. Ein Kommentar ist der falsche Ort, eine Frage zu stellen. Klicke auf »Ask Question« rechts oben. 2. "to place" = "platzieren". "to put" = "geben". "to set" = setzen. 3. *Der* Gegenstand ist männlich. Richtig wäre daher »... absolut jede**r** Gegenstand ...«